# How to set limit on request header in flask use with flask_limiter?

Tags: python, redis, limit, flask-restful

**Can i set limit on http request  header in flask?**

My request header is store in redis and One is added for each request in redis.
for example:

**one** : 3

**tow** : 5

...

one , tow and ... is my request header by key= CLIENT-KEY.

---

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    limiter = Limiter(
        app,
        key_func=get_remote_address,
        default_limits=["200 per day", "50 per hour"]
    )
    
    redis_cache = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0,
                              password='redis', charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
    
    number = 0
    
    
    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    @limiter.limit("1 per minute", key_func=get_remote_address)
    def api_message():
        try:
            target = request.headers['CLIENT-KEY']
            global number
            if redis_cache.__contains__(target):
                a = int(redis_cache.get(target))
                redis_cache.set(target, a + 1)
    
                return redis_cache.get(target)
    
            else:
                number = 0
                number += 1
                redis_cache.set(target, number)
                return redis_cache.get(target)
    
        except:
            my_key_list = redis_cache.keys()
            return redis_cache.get(target)
```

**NOW HOW CAN I LIMIT REQUEST HEADER?**

for example:
each CLIENT-KEY can request only 10 per minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved the problem**

---

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
from flask import jsonify
from flask_limiter import Limiter



def get_client_key():
    return request.headers.get('CLIENT-KEY')


app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(app, key_func=get_client_key)





@app.errorhandler(429)
def ratelimit_handler(e):
    return make_response(
        jsonify(
            {"message": f"Too many request from {request.headers.get('CLIENT-KEY')}"}), 429
    )


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@limiter.limit('10/minute')
```

---

This [link](https://github.com/rezacloner1372/arvan/blob/main/limitCounter/api/api/api.py) might be helpful you. this is my github repo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need some dynamic limit. You can access your request headers like below:

```
from flask import request
request.headers.get('your-header-name')
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906520/how-to-set-dynamic-limit-for-pluggable-views-using-flask) might be helpful for how to define some dynamic limit.